# How to upgrade node without affecting existing node modules?

Tags: node.js

I want to upgrade my node server. I have lot of dependencies on my node modules. I want to run my application with the upgraded server, When I tried my express, node-sass codes are breaking..

Is there a way to upgrade having a fallback for older versions of node modules?

Comment: Why are you upgrading? If it works, leave it as it is and use `nvm` as described below to run that server with your current version of node. Then upgrade to the latest for future work.

Comment: The node-sass version is old and lacks support for latest features, we want to upgrade it to the latest version, node-sass@3.x.x requires higher version of node server..

Comment: Then you'll need to upgrade all of your modules to more current versions and then run your Unit Tests to assure everything works as expected. You do have Unit Tests, don't you? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to switch between different node versions, you can simply use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), which works very well.

But I'm not sure what you need - do you have several applications running at the same time who need different Node versions? If this is the case, I suggest you use NVM the following way:

- Install the versions of node you need: `nvm install v4.2.4`, `nvm install v0.10.36`, ...
- You will have the corresponding node executables in the directories `/home/YOURUSERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/vYOUR_VERSION/bin/`
- Use the version of node each application needs to run it

  - `/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.4/bin/node app-needing-node-4.2.4.js`
  - `/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v0.10.36/bin/node app-needing-node-0.10.36.js`

You can also shorten the command by creating symbolic links:

`sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.4/bin/node /usr/bin/node-v4.2.4`

After that, you can use the command `node-v4.2.4` when needed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I have made my question more clearer and specific, have a look..

Comment: Maybe try to reinstall your node modules? `cd your_project && rm -rf node_modules && npm install`